# What does mean "Managed environment not provisioned"

Tags: azure

I am trying to create Container App. All required fields were properly set and system review shown me green light. But after clicking "create" build fails with exception - "ManagedEnvironmentNotProvisioned". What does it mean? What I didn't provide?

Comment: Experiencing this too - did you come to any conclusion?